# Colors artifacts/jittering after render - filmora

Tags: rendering

Hi I'm having some issues with colors in my video, I have still images that after the render jitter

[image: Jittering]

Never seen something like this, any idea why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is everything else on the screen stationary, or is there other movement in other parts of the screen? If there is, I'd put it down to lossy codecs like h264.
Try exporting at a higher bitrate. You could add a tiny amount of noise or grain to the video which might reduce the jittering at the overall expense of detail.